# How to duplicate each characters in a string and how to insert $ in between each characters in a string

Tags: r, regex

I want to duplicate each characters in R Studio

```
a <- c("abcd")
```

I want the result to be

```
"aabbccdd"
```

I tried

```
strrep(a, 2)
```

But it gives me `"abcdabcd"`

Another thing I'm trying to do is:

I want the result to be `"a$b$c$d"`, inserting `$` in between each characters

Can anyone help? the simpler the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**gsub**

```
gsub("(.)", "\\1\\1", a)
#[1] "aabbccdd"

gsub("(.)", "\\1$", a)
#[1] "a$b$c$d$"
```

**strsplit**

```
sapply(strsplit(a, ""), function(x) paste(rep(x, each = 2), collapse = ""))
#[1] "aabbccdd"

sapply(strsplit(a, ""), function(x) paste(paste0(x, "$"), collapse = ""))
#[1] "a$b$c$d$"
```

**substring**

```
sapply(a, function(x)
    paste(rep(substring(x, sequence(nchar(x)), sequence(nchar(x))), each = 2), collapse = ""))
#      abcd 
#"aabbccdd" 

sapply(a, function(x)
    paste(paste0(substring(x, sequence(nchar(x)), sequence(nchar(x))), "$"), collapse = ""))
#      abcd 
#"a$b$c$d$"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I need. I understand gsub function, but can you explain why the pattern is "(.)"? I guess replacement "\\1" means the string itself, right?

Answer (score 1):

A different solution:

```
paste(unlist(lapply(1:nchar(a), function(k) rep(substr(a,k,k),2))), collapse="")
# [1] "aabbccdd"

paste(unlist(lapply(1:nchar(a), function(k) rep(substr(a,k,k),1))), collapse="$")
# [1] "a$b$c$d"
```